# What is the sum of the series? $\sum_{i=0}^{K+N-3}\left\lfloor \frac{i}{N-1} \right\rfloor$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, direct-sum

> What is the sum of the series given by  $$\sum_{i=0}^{K+N-3}\left\lfloor \frac{i}{N-1} \right\rfloor$$ Where $N \in [2,100000)$ and $k \in [1,100000)$

Please help me find the first term and last term of the ap so I can find the sum of this series? 
if n =2 and k= 6, then answer is 15
if n= 3 and k=7 then answer is 12

Comment: Please [show context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) by including what you have tried.

Comment: if k= 6 and n =2 then I am unable to make any kind of series? the answer is 15 if  k =2 n=3, then answer is  1 and if n =3 and k =7, then answer is  12.

Comment: if you can give an example of a case like n =2 and k =6?? The answer given is 15

Comment: ok now I am starting to get it, so what can be  its first term and last term so that I that can calculate the sum sn = n/2(a+l)

Comment: Sorry, I meant $15$ in my last comment (that was a typo).

Comment: What is the source of the question? I'm just curious since we cannot answer any questions for an ongoing contest or competition.

Answer (score 0):

Work in progress:

**Hint**

You should first change variables so that $U = N - 1$ to simplify the problem. Then the problem becomes: $$\sum_{i = 0}^{K+U-2} \left\lfloor\frac{i}{U} \right\rfloor ;\  u \in [1, 10^5), k \in [1, 10^5)$$

Notice from [the graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ratqyh4tok) that the sum from $0$ to $U$ is $0$, from $0$ to $2U$ is U, from $0$ to $3U$ is $3U$, from $0$ to $4U$ is $6U$ and so on. Using the formula for triangular numbers, the sum from $0$ to $\lfloor{K+U-2}\rfloor$ will be $\frac{1}{2} \left(U \cdot \lfloor \frac{K+U-4}{U} \rfloor \right) \left(U \cdot \lfloor \frac{K+U-4}{U} \rfloor+1 \right)$, and then you can add the last few terms by hand.

Now change variables back to $N$.

*Added after comment:*

With $N=3, K=7$, we have $U=2$. So the summation becomes:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{7+2-2} \left\lfloor\frac{i}{2} \right\rfloor $$

Using the formula, we have $U \cdot \left  \lfloor \frac{(K+U-4)}{U} \right \rfloor = 2 \cdot \left \lfloor\frac{7+2-4}{2} \right \rfloor = 4$, which rounds to the greatest integer that is on the next 'step' down. Therefore, the sum from $will be $\frac{4(4+1)}{2}$